# A self intersecting surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, surfaces

Consider the surface

${\bf{x}}(u,v)=\big(a\,\sin{u}\,\sin(2v),\,a\,\cos{u},\,a\,\sin{u}\,\sin{v}\big)\,,\quad a>0,\,\; u\in[0,\pi)\,,\; v\in[0,2\pi)\,.$

[image: self intersecting surface]

I'm interested for any of its topological or geometrical properties (this is not some homework task!). For example: is it orientable? (except of its "poles" $(0,-a,0)$ and $(0,a,0)$). Is there any well known surface to which is homotopically equivalent? 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This isn’t a surface in the usual topological sense; it’s “singular” in the middle. It’s homotopy equivalent to a wedge of two spheres.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You are right! I should write "[branched surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branched_surface)"